# App rejected, insert valid contact information

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Play console reject my aggregation news app. I get posts link by some RSS feed.
After submitted app Google response to me with a rejection for:

- Does not contain a website or in-app page that provides valid contact information for the news publisher

Google is not clear, this is the email i have receved:

[Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCXQt.png)

and this is the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wdAe.png)

What contact information must I insert? Can I have some example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem, adding a new page with link to about page of all my RSS feed.

Comment: I have the same issues. where do I add a new page in apps or in the website?

Comment: You need to add in app...

Comment: can you please share the new page with link to about page layout screenshot?

Comment: Thanks. Added in about page in apps. now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to add some sort of privacy policy or user agreements inti your app and play developer console.

Comment: I resolve this problem, adding a new page with link to about page of all my RSS feed